# Touchscreen Gestures Not Working Properly on LattePanda with Xubuntu (XFCE4) & Qt App

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I'm hoping to get some assistance with a touchscreen issue on a LattePanda board running Xubuntu20.04.6 LTS (XFCE4 environment). We have a Qt application designed for this setup, but we're encountering a problem:

Issue: The system doesn't fully support touchscreen gestures. The screen displays a cursor, making it appear like a mouse-controlled system.
Goal: We want to disable the cursor and enable a full touchscreen experience with gestures for our application.

Constraints:
We're working on a Single-Board Computer (SBC) with limited resources.
Xubuntu with XFCE4 is preferred due to its lightweight nature. Changing the environment is not an option.

Questions:
Are there any configuration options within Xubuntu/XFCE4 to enable full touchscreen functionality and disable the cursor?
Are there Qt libraries or settings that can be adjusted within our application to improve touchscreen gesture support?
Does anyone have experience with similar setups on LattePanda boards and have solutions to share?

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS questions are still on topic; Xubuntu 20.04 LTS however is EOL; https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/20.04/release-notes where you'll note "*supported for three years until Saturday, April 29, 2023*". (Your question should focus on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using Xfce).  You've also tagged *Ubuntu-touch* which is the phone OS supported by UBports Foundation - refer* https://ubports.com/  (ie. Lomiri desktop is used and not Xfce) .. your Xfce is old, using older libraries (with fewer features)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on tag details!

Comment: Can you tell any equivalent alternatives to xfce4 desktop environment that consumes low resources similar to xfce4.